# How to stop my android NFC scanning when I close an activity?

Tags: android, nfc

I'm developing an app about nfc scanning. It will start the activity anyway when it close to NFC tags(even the app is not running).
 Now i want the app start NFC scanning when i open the app, and close sanning when i close an activity. Simply speaking, i want to add a controller for NFC scanning.

Comment: i don't fully understand your question, you want to stop scaning for nfc tags right?

Answer (score 0):

Use an intent filter to launch your app when scanning a NFC tag. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#filtering-intents

To scan for NFC tags while your app is running, use [enableForegroundDispatch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableForegroundDispatch(android.app.Activity, android.app.PendingIntent, android.content.IntentFilter[], java.lang.String[][])).

You can stop scanning by calling [disableForegroundDispatch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#disableForegroundDispatch(android.app.Activity)). You'll want to disable foreground dispatch in onPause().

Comment: Is there any something like `disableBackgroundDispach`? I want to disable the deep link which pops up everywhere on OS while I am using my application.